# Difference between two groups of percentages?

Tags: statistical-significance, percentage

I have linked a GoogleSheet which shows the grade % my company was given on customer service at the end of every week in 2020 and 2021. The % is how well we did that week. 100% is perfect, and we're rarely (if ever) below 95%. I'm trying to tell if there is a significant difference between 2020 and 2021, primarily if we did better in 2021 than in 2020. I created a line chart to try and visualize a difference but I was hoping for a more concrete number (a statistical test output perhaps?) of how the two years compare.

Is there a statistical test which can compare two group of scores (where the scores are all percentages) and tell me if they are different in a way that's significant and how big that difference is? Ideally, we'd be looking for 2021 to have better customer service than 2020.  Link to spreadsheet below:

[Weekly Service Grade %](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m2zIbIDLQECCzFQwg0b2359OpWVrEhtxrmdpikVt_PU/edit#gid=2136453530)

Comment: Do these come from people rating your company?  If so, do you have the number of ratings (e.g. the number of people who participated in the survey or something)

Comment: The rating is a % of how many loads we delivered on time. It's not a subjective measure by people. Basically if we have to deliver 100 loads that week and we only get 90 done then we get 90% as our grade that week. The best way to think of the grade we get each week would be like a student getting a grade on a weekly quiz in school.

Comment: Maybe you could use a control chart? Look through the tag [tag:quality-control]